# Bootstrap grid does not display properly when one of the elements gains height when width is shrunk

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

Here is how my divs are defined:

```
<div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2">
    <input type="checkbox" id="collectionFilter_Agriculture" name="collectionFilter" class="collectionFilter vis-hidden" value="0" data-count="0" data-ng-true-value="0" data-ng-click="filterByCollection('0')">
    <label for="collectionFilter_Agriculture" class="collectionFilterLabel noselect" data-ng-class="{disabled: collectionFilter.length > 0 &amp;&amp; collectionArray.indexOf('0') === -1}">Agriculture</label>
</div>
```

Here is how they look normally

[image: Normal]

Here is how they look when the viewport width is shrunk. You can see the "Zoology and Biology" div, instead of moving to the next line, takes up and entire line by itself, for instance.
[image: Messed up]

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using Boostrap 3 which uses `float` to layout columns. You can learn more about float [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float).

You can either override Bootsrap's CSS or use a more [recent version](https://getbootstrap.com/) (Bootstrap 4)

Here's an example of what you can do to override this behavior using `display: inline-block` :

```
.row {  
  font-size: 0;  /* this removes the white-space in the row */

  > [class*="col-"] {
    display: inline-block!important;
    vertical-align: top; /* you can use either top, middle or bottom */
    float: none!important; /* removing bootstrap's float */
    font-size: 1rem; /* restoring font-size */
  }
}
```

I advise adding a new class name for the row to do this override and not use `.row`

Comment: That didn't work. Same issue. The only thing I have found to work is Bootstrap's cleartext. Since I'm building these divs dynamically I had to do this:       if (x%6===0) h+='<div class="clearfix"><!-- clearfix md cols every 6 --></div>'
    else if (x%3===0) h+='<div class="clearfix visible-xs"><!-- clearfix xs cols every 3 --></div>'

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could get this to work was to insert cleartext divs at the appropriate place in the dom:

```
if (x%6===0) h+='<div class="clearfix"></div>'
else if (x%3===0) h+='<div class="clearfix visible-xs"></div>'
```